# How to export value to another const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using react-google-recaptcha to generate invisible ReCaptcha and I need to use the token in another const.

The token is generating correctly, but I don't know how to pass it on to another location. How should I do this?

```
   const onTextSubmit = async () => {
        let recaptchaToken;
        if (recaptchaLoaded) {
          recaptchaToken = await recaptcha.current.execute();
        }
        
        // How to export recaptchaToken?
      };
```

I need to get the recaptchaToken and use it here:

```
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormInput> = (data) => {
    formCreateMutation.mutate({
      data,
      recaptchaToken,
    });
  };
```

The two const are in the same file, I'm using react to do that.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using a framework (like react)? Is the onTextSubsmit and the onSubmit in the same file?

Comment: @Poku Yes! I edited my question with this infos

Comment: Do you want to call the onSubmit inside the onTextSubmit? Or wait for a button press or other later action?

Answer (score -1):

You are not posting all code from the component but you can store the recaptchaToken value in react state like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [recaptchaToken, setRecaptchaToken] = useState(undefined);

  const onTextSubmit = async () => {
    if (recaptchaLoaded) {
      const value = await recaptcha.current.execute();
      setRecaptchaToken(value);
    }
    
    // How to export recaptchaToken?
  };

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormInput> = (data) => {
    if (recaptchaToken) {
      formCreateMutation.mutate({
        data,
        recaptchaToken,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{recaptchaToken}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```